# Pytube Error: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to download YouTube playlist from url "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyVYfSNb_Pc&list=PLBxwSeQlMDNiNt72UmSvKBLsxPgGY_Jy-", but getting the error 'get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple'.

Code block is:

`

```
from pytube import Playlist

play_list = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyVYfSNb_Pc&list=PLBxwSeQlMDNiNt72UmSvKBLsxPgGY_Jy-')

print(f'Downloading: {play_list.title}')

for video in play_list.videos:
    print(video.title)
    st = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    st.download(r'path')  `
```

i am using the latest version of pytube.

Comment: The error seems to be happening internally in pytube. Why don't you use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)? It's more powerful and reliable in general.

Comment: I had a perfectly working scripts with pytube, but suddenly (1-2 days ago) I no longer can get streams from YouTube object and now getting the error: "get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple". But YouTube object still constructs successfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Becuase youtube changed something on its end, and now you have to change pytube's ciper.py's `function_patterns` to the following

```
r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&\s*'
r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]{2,3})(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)'
```

And you also have to change line 288 to this:

```
nfunc=re.escape(function_match.group(1))),
```

You'll have to use this workaround until pytube officially releases a fix.

Comment: There is a pull request currently open with this fix: https://github.com/pytube/pytube/pull/1312