# Pytube error when I'm trying download video

Tags: python, video, download, youtube, pytube

When I tried to download video with **pytube** there was error: **pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError**: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883661/pytube-error-get-throttling-function-name-could-not-find-match-for-multiple) here, but when I tried it didn't work. (if it's only decision please send all code of cipher.py)

Here's the code

```
from pytube import YouTube

stream = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBQprWeOx8g").streams.get_highest_resolution()
stream.download('video.mp4')
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgarde pytube to 12.0.0

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

Then if you get error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
go to your python root folder like:

`C:\Users\#\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pytube\parser.py`

Change this line: `152: func_regex = re.compile(r"function\([^)]+\)")`

to this: `152: func_regex = re.compile(r"function\([^)]?\)")`

if it doesn't work then try : in pytube/cipher.py on line 311:

change : `name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))`

to : `name = "hha"`

Comment: here's another error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'

Comment: what's your python version?

Comment: Python version 3.10.0

Comment: Have a look into the edit and try it

Comment: same error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span' (I'm working with Pycharm and it has another folder with libraries)

Comment: in pytube/cipher.py on line 311: change : name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))    to name = "hha"

Comment: don't work too, same error

Comment: Have a look at : [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945080/pytube-exceptions-regexmatcherror-get-throttling-function-name-could-not-find) Maybe you need to change in pattern

Comment: pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_initial_function_name: could not find match for multiple with first; regex_search: could not find match for \$x\[0\]=function\(\w\){[a-z=\.\(\"\)]*;(.*);(?:.+)} with second

Comment: @TadevosyanMikael have you checked [pytube GitHub site?](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+None) - probably they have reported the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue.

Tracing the error, it seems like the point of failure was at 286 of cipher.py

```
array = re.search(
    r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\]);'.format(
        nfunc=re.escape(function_match.group(1))),
    js
)
```

This line is supposed to find a particular assignment within the youtubeObject.js it's given, and in my case the line in question did in fact exist and looked like this:

`var Msa=[ema],Jsa=!1;`

Now I'm pretty sure it's that comma that's throwing a wrench in things, the regex is expecting the line to end in a plain semicolon and since the line it would have found did not have a ; after the ], array found None and threw the error

I edited line 287 from

```
r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\]);'.format(
```

to

```
r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\])[;,]'.format(
```

in order for it to be able to match either the assignment being on its own or the assignment being done together with a second variable (as it was here)

Unfortunately I am an amateur and can't reliably tell you where the packages are located, but in my figuring this out I reinstalled python via the microsoft store and my cipher.py is located at `C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py`