# pytube throwing 'get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple' error while trying to download YouTube videos

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I'm using the pytube library in my Python project to download YouTube videos. Everything was working fine until recently, when I started getting an error from pytube. I'm sure my pytube is up-to-date.

Here's the function where I use pytube:

`

```
# from pytube import YouTube
# import base64

# Get the video
video = YouTube(audio_link)

# Create a buffer
buffer = io.BytesIO()

# Download audio stream into memory
audio_stream = video.streams.get_audio_only()
audio_stream.stream_to_buffer(buffer)

# Base64 encode audio bytes
b64 = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()

if download_link:
    # Create download link and write to Streamlit
    href = f'<a href="data:audio/mp3;base64,{b64}" download="{meeting_name}.mp3">Download audio file</a>'
    st.markdown(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)

meeting_audio = buffer.getvalue()


# Close the buffer
buffer.close()
```

`

When the function tries to run video = YouTube(audio_link), it throws the following error:

**get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple**

I've tried using different YouTube links, and the error is the same. Updating pytube to the latest version didn't solve the issue either.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was already answered [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883661/pytube-error-get-throttling-function-name-could-not-find-match-for-multiple). But to sum it up, there is a problem with pytube since YouTube made some changes internally. I'd suggest you to use some other libraries like yt-dl instead.

Comment: The link is not working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Youtube made more changes, and now the expression pytube had does not work.
I played around with it and got this one working:

r'a.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*([a-z]\s*=\s*a.get("n"))\s*&&\s*([a-z]\s*=.*|([a-zA-Z0-9$]*)'

replace lines 272, 273 with this and it should work.

god bless regex

Comment: Damn unreadable code.

Comment: It's regex, unreadable by design.

Answer (score 0):

I found it on github homepage, it worked for me [here](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1684),